# How can I display animated text in C#

Tags: c#, forms, animation, text

I have a connect four championship game. Is there a way in which I can display text in an animated way? What I mean is, after each round display Round 1 written on the screen.. after round 1 is over display ROUND 2.

What I mean is display text not in the form as a label but like in online games when they display text just appearing on the screen and disappearing after a few seconds.. don't know if it's possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually draw it on the form by getting the form Graphics object when the game is won.

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawString("Game Won!", DefaultFont, Brushes.Red, x,y);
```

Where this is the form in context and x,y are the coordinates to draw your text

of course as others have mentioned you'll have to do a timer that will change the x,y or other properties such as the font size every animation frame. You'll want to do that on a separate thread and double buffer the results

Comment: Yes this is a good idea thanks a lot! but can I paint on several components on a form? If you just do Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics(); , I would be creating graphics for all the form, yes? So the painted Item will be on top of all components and then I just clear it after the time is over?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure as winforms doesn't let you really play with the zindex of items, you might have to draw on the topmost item. It's really not a suitable platform for this. 

Start by just trying to draw a string, don't worry about the animation. You can always just add a new Panel control to the form when the game is won on top of everything and draw on it.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you can make a custom control and overwrite the OnPaint method to create the animation on it, centered and proportional and just add it to the top of the form.

Comment: yes I suppose I can do that.. if the panel on top can be transparent so that the other components are still visible behind the string!

Comment: I remember needing to do something similar and I'm pretty sure you can't make a transparent panel.

Comment: no you can't in fact :/ well I suppose C# forms arent ideal for these types of animations and some real graphics!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly mean by animation, but in general, you could create a timer that would 'animate' your text the way you want it to animate, like in every 20 millisecond or so. So for example, if you want to move your text simply from right to left, you would set `myText.X += 5` or something alike, in your timer elapsed handler.

Comment: What I mean is display text not in the form as a label but like in online games when they display text just appearing on the screen and disappearing after a few seconds.. don't know if it's possible!

Comment: @studentProgrammer:  Pop up a tooltip? Or use a timer to set `myLabel.Visible = false` after a few seconds.

Comment: hmm I can display a label and make it visible after some seconds yes, but is there a way in which a label is in front of every other component in a form? and what is a tooltip please? I am new to forms, never used it before! Thanks for your help!